# Render result does not appear when file is reopened

Tags: rendering

I can't find the rendered image result. The render work perfectly but when I reopen the file there is only a blank grey screen. This has not happended before.Please help.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times, you have already asked it here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46610/rendered-result-lost

Answer (score 2):

Blender **does not save the render result** with the file.  If you close the file without saving the render it will be lost.

---

You can save a rendered image by going to *Image* > *Save Image* in the UV/Image Editor (hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

[image]

If you need to save all the render layers and passes with extended dynamic range for future post-processing in Blender, you can save to a [Multilayer Open-EXR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR) image file and import it into the compositor next time with an *Image* node.

[image]

---

Also see: [How to save the render result within Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/how-to-save-the-render-result-within-blender?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the image before closing the file. In UV image editor click *Image* > *Save Image* or <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd>.