# Rendered image disappeared when I re-opened my project

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am using Windows 10 and am perfectly able to use the application . but i am not able to open my saved projects  i am able to see in edit mode but the opened rendered image does not load . i have to reclick render and wait for it again.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

See this thread: [How to save the render result within Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/how-to-save-the-render-result-within-blender)

Blender does not store renders in the .blend files.  They are stored in RAM until you exit the program, at which time the OS deallocates all applicable memory.  If you want to store the image, you must save it yourself by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> In the UV editor window.  You can set the options beforehand in the Properties menu:

[image]

Or in the Save window:

[image]