# Pack rendered images into .blend?

Tags: rendering, saving, packed-data

I have a problem: I render images, and if Blender accidentally quits while performing some sort of operation, I lose my rendered data. (If only a single unsaved image).

I have **external data > 'Pack all into .blend'** enabled, but this does not pack rendered images into the file.

Is there a way to pack *single rendered images* into the .blend along with all of my already packed textures?

This would be extremely helpful, and would save a lot of render time!

Comment: Hello :). It seems Blender can't save the render result by itself. But you can save it as a Multilayer EXR, open in image editor and then pack.

Comment: It's also discussed here https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/18964/78972

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you want to automatically save the rendered result so if Blender crashes you have the last known output.  Using composition you can save the output as follows:

[image]

This image, by default, will be called Image0001.png in your chosen path. If you really really really wanted to pack it in the Blender file I suppose you could create a non-rendered object that takes that image and then it should also be stored (*not tested*). However, I think just the automatic saving is probably what you are after.