# saving rendered image with project so when project is opened later, rendered image is there?

Tags: saving

Still new to blender and learning some of the shortcuts and procedures, but I notice that when a project is saved, the rendered image isn't automatically saved with it (or if it is, I don't know the directory).  Now I know I can save the image itself before closing and have been, but it would be nice to have it as part of the project so that when reopened, it is there.

Some searching here brought me across a nine year old post saying that rendered images were not auto saved with the project.  Is this still true, or is there now a way to save rendered image with project?  If not, should I refer back to the nine year old post, or is there a better way?  Thank you.

EDIT:  Ok, so I tried the #3 option mentioned here:

[How to save the render result within Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/how-to-save-the-render-result-within-blender)

I saved to the Multi-Layer-EXR image as suggested, opened in UV/image editor, packed, and saved the project.  When reopened, I unpacked (choosing the first option in the unpack menu), but the rendered image did not reappear in the project. If there's something I'm missing, please inform, otherwise I don't think this is going to work.

Comment: not that I know, you need to put your mouse over the render pop-up, which is an Image Editor window, and press Alt S

Comment: No, images are still not saved automatically with the project. Other image textures are not saved with a project either unless you pack them into the file - but there the reason is to have everything which is needed for the scene in a single file. Rendered images are output. If you want to save them on disk automatically after rendering, you can use a _File Output_ node in the _Compositor_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann BTW, now when you quit Blender, it asks you to save (pack) the images. Still not ideal, because you can press CTRL+S many times through many days without actually closing Blender, and then when it crashes - the image is not saved automatically (though I would have to test if it's saved in the recover-auto save)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, I wasn't going into detail in regards to packing, because this only asks for images from texture painting or opened images which you edited etc., not rendered images what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

So after saving the original render as a Multi-Layer-EXR, and returning to Blender later,  I was able to go into compositing and importing the image using an image node.  Not quite the same as requested, but will be good enough for now.  I can add nodes and various effects and then render the single image and save the new result.